# How to switch Z and Y key in Serbo-Croatian (US)?

Tags: swap, keys

What file should i edit in /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found it!
It is inside file: us, under "hbs"
I replaced Z with Y and added Z to what was previously Y.
After modification it looks like this:

```
// Serbian charecters added as third level symbols to US keyboard layout.

partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "hbs" {

  include "us"
  name[Group1]= "Serbo-Croatian (US)";

  key <TLDE> { [ grave, asciitilde ] };
  key <AE06> { [ 6, dead_caron, asciicircum, asciicircum ] };
  key <AE08> { [ 8, asterisk, multiply, division ] };
  key <AE11> { [ minus, underscore, endash, emdash ] };
  key <AC09> { [ l, L, U1C9, U1C8 ] };
  key <AB06> { [ n, N, U1CC, U1CB ] };
  key <AB01> { [ y, Y, U1C6, U1C5 ] };
  key <AD06> { [ z, Z ] };
  key <AD03> { [ e, E, EuroSign, cent ] };
  key <AC03> { [ d, D, dstroke, Dstroke ] };
  key <AC11> { [ dead_acute, quotedbl, apostrophe, apostrophe ] };
  key <SPCE> { [ space, space, nobreakspace, nobreakspace ] };
  key <AB08> { [ comma, less, U3003, guillemotright ] };
  key <AB09> { [ period, greater, ellipsis, guillemotleft ] };

  include "level3(ralt_switch)"
};
```